# Google Play Services Signin Only Works With Signed APK

Tags: android, google-play-services

My app only lets me sign in to the Google Play Services only when I am using a signed version of my APK. I want to be able to sign in without a signed version of my APK. I get this message if it is not signed.

`The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in the Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information.`

The account I am signing in with is listed as a tester account. The package name is correct.

Comment: Just a reminder: all Android apps are signed per [Signing Your Application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) - debug versions (which are used to sign the app during development) are signed with a debug key usually in your home directory `.android/debug.keystore`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the certificate used for generating the client ID is different from the one used for signing..

Either change setting in eclipse to use proper signing certificate by default or change the settings in google play..